# are mht files supported in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013

Are .mht files supported in SharePoint 2013?

For viewing the PPT files, in 2010, there files were saved as .mht files and they were uploaded to a document library and the mht file link was shown using a page viewer webpart

Is this still supported?

Comment: Yes, it's working in SP2013 are you facing a specific issue? or just need to confirm that

Comment: Recently migrated a 2010 portal to 2013, the mht files are getting downloaded when I open the page

Comment: should you try to run that PowerShell to be able to show it in browser  $webapp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "webapplicationurl"
    $webapp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("message/rfc822")
    $webapp.Update()

Comment: sure will give it a try
Thanks for the help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's supported in SharePoint 2013.

In a case of you are not able to show `.mht file` in browser.you will need to run the below PoweShell cmdlet

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "webapplicationurl"
$webapp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("message/rfc822")
$webapp.Update()
```

For more details check [PowerShell Ref](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/741b93d4-8402-48bc-a41d-584c8402e6bd/not-able-to-open-mht-file-directly-in-browser-from-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: What mime type should I add for HTM files? (.htm)
They are getting downloaded when I give the link in pageviewer webpart

Comment: Bro, should you try this "text/html"